# Cost of indexed view versus filtered index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I have met the following table design for recording references in non-normalized way:

```
RecordGUID              uniqueidentifier
DestinationEntity       uniqueidentifier
DestinationRecordGUID   uniqueidentifier
```

For example for `Users` table to describe references to `Countries`, we will have:

```
 RecordGUID                             DestinationEntity                       DestinationRecordGUID   
 79282C80-4474-4617-9C40-C21E97F5AC52   3A462EF8-DAB6-4B98-BA1B-FBD957A1737C    5842E524-8C5D-4DEE-A553-0857FB9C12F4
 B25DA064-8DAF-4EEB-8894-D540B3A929EA   3A462EF8-DAB6-4B98-BA1B-FBD957A1737C    C2B0AA1A-E688-4E2C-BD5F-16309C496774
```

So, the `3A462EF8-DAB6-4B98-BA1B-FBD957A1737C` means `Countries`, while `5842E524-8C5D-4DEE-A553-0857FB9C12F4` and `C2B0AA1A-E688-4E2C-BD5F-16309C496774` are referring records in `Counries` table.

We are having many relations here - for example, `users` to `languages`, `companies`, etc. And because working with `GUID` in order to join the tables is not user friendly, we have indexed view for each relation like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[users_countries]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT [RecordGUID]
      ,[DestinationEntity]
      ,[DestinationRecordGUID]
FROM (the relationship table)
WHERE [DestinationEntity] = '3A462EF8-DAB6-4B98-BA1B-FBD957A1737C';
```

as a result one can easily make a join with this view to the `counties` table and query it - also, because of using the view (with no expand) and having a index on it, not all records from the original table are read (it's faster).

The system may have hundreds of indexed views and I am worried about the cost of the engine to manage them, compare to filtered indexes on the original table. I mean instead having a `view` just to create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX (index_Name) ON (the relationship table)
(
    [RecordGUID]
   ,[DestinationRecordGUID]
)
WHERE [DestinationEntity] = '3A462EF8-DAB6-4B98-BA1B-FBD957A1737C'
```

We are not able to query in a friendly way the table anymore, but will this affect the performance?

I was not able to find any topics about indexed view hurting the performance - but facing such design makes me doubting.

I am wondering can we say that the maintenance of the index of a view and the same index on a table (like the above) is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design is terrible.  You should have separate tables and real foreign keys.  For a quick fix, use the indexed views.  If there are perf problems, fix the design.

Comment: I know. I am more interested what's the cost of having, so many indexed views and if it can be compared with having indexes. I have never met something like this before (system with hundreds indexed views) and want to understand the internals of managing them.

Comment: Indexed views are indexes, so the cost should be similar.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I will try to change the design, but for now the indexed views will be used...